# Why does kafkaManager fail to Run Reassign Partitions

Tags: apache-kafka

I expanded the kafka with the original 3 nodes and added 4 nodes.
Then I use KafkaManager to Run Partition Assignments. but I get the follow error.

[image]

```
2023-04-26 14:14:09,285 - [WARN] - from kafka.manager.actor.cluster.KafkaManagedOffsetCache in KafkaManagedOffsetCache 
Failed to process a message from offset topic on cluster kafka-cluster!
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Unknown group metadata version 3
        at kafka.manager.utils.one10.GroupMetadataManager$.schemaForGroupValue(GroupMetadataManager.scala:554)
        at kafka.manager.utils.one10.GroupMetadataManager$.readGroupMessageValue(GroupMetadataManager.scala:726)
        at kafka.manager.actor.cluster.KafkaManagedOffsetCache.$anonfun$run$3(KafkaStateActor.scala:377)
        at kafka.manager.actor.cluster.KafkaManagedOffsetCache.$anonfun$run$3$adapted(KafkaStateActor.scala:325)
        at scala.util.Success.foreach(Try.scala:253)
        at kafka.manager.actor.cluster.KafkaManagedOffsetCache.run(KafkaStateActor.scala:325)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I want to know how to slove it.

Comment: Any more logs ?

Comment: ok, more logs have been added.

Comment: There's a package called `zero81` in the stacktrace... I assume that refers to kafka 0.8.1, which is super old and may no longer work with Kafka 3+

Comment: @User9527, what is you kafka version on all nodes ? Are they all the same ?